# PHP. Return random values from an array, but not equals

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, random, equals

I have in array 6 values, I need to return 4 random values from an array, but all shouldn't be equal.

Example:

If I have an array (6 values) `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` I need to get 4 random values from it for example `3, 1, 4, 2`. For now It returning for example: `2,2,3,2`

Here is code:

```
$array= array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
$k = array_rand($array);
$random_element = $array[$k];
echo $random_element;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle) the array and then [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) some elements from it:

```
shuffle($array);
$random_elements = array_slice($array, 0, 4); // with 4 the number of random values
```

Comment: Thank you forr answer. It returns ArrayArrayArrayArray

Comment: @Infinity well, you need to foreach over the array with random elements, like `foreach ($random_elements as $value) { echo $value; }`

Comment: @Infinity answer is right, if you want as string then implode it with `,` . +1 for small and crisp answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your old functionallity with `echo` just insert an `unset` into your loop

```
$array= array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $k = array_rand($array);
    $random_element = $array[$k];

    unset($array[$k]);

    echo $random_element;
}
```

But I like bwoebi's solution more.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array= array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
$k = array_rand($array);

$random_element = $array[$k];
unset($array[$k]);  
echo $random_element;
}
```

1. get the random value from array
2. remove the element from array, so that during next iteration we wont get repeated element

Comment: please add some explanation of your code, showing what it does and how it solves the problem. This will help others who see your answer in the future